# Install laravel ends up in wrong directory (composer with cygwin)

Tags: command-line, path, cygwin, package, composer-php

I am trying to install laravel with the use of cygwin, a command line tool for windows.

I use this line

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel=4.2.0 c/my_workspace/projectname --prefer-dist
```

which installs everything. But it does not end up in c:/my_workspace/projectname. Instead it ends up in **cygwin64**/c/my_workspace/projectname.

The next time I tried it it ended up in a different folder, also inside "cygwin64".

It doesn't matter what path I specify, the path will start in the cygwin64 folder for some reason. By the way, in cygwin there is a always a prefix for the paths called /cygdrive/. Is that what causes it to start from cygwin64?

I also tried instead to execute it from **cmd** by navigating to

```
cd c:/myworkspace
```

And then entering

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel=4.2.0 /projectname --prefer-dist
```

It says "Installling", and then "loading from cache" (?), then it says

```
 failed to download laravel/laravel from dist: C:my_workspace/vendor/composer/5079c43b does not exist and could not be created
```

Then it tries to download from source. When cloning starts it fails:

```
Failed to clone git@github.com:laravel/laravel.git, git was not found
```

Comment: 1. I'm just wondering, should not be the correct path with colon - **:**? Thus `c:/my_workspace/projectname`?

2. As for the `composer create-project laravel/laravel=4.2.0 /projectname --prefer-dist`, try `projectname` without slash before it.

Comment: Yes you're right. I think I tried different things, and when I specified a correct path, it wouldn't install because of permission problems (running as administrator fixed that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it installed finally. I suppose there was something wrong with the way I wrote the filepath:

```
c/my_workspace/projectname
```

so it was created in the cygwin64 folder (for some reason). This time I navigated to the folder where I want the install:

```
cd c:/my_workspace/projectname
```

then install with:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel=4.2.0 --prefer-dist
```

However, I got a mkdir() permission denied problem, which was solved by running cygwin as administrator.

Then I got another problem where you setup the laravel development server with

```
$ php artisan serve
```

It could not find the artisan file because it was located inside a "laravel" folder(!?), which I guess wasn't right, so I moved the laravel files back to my project folder and deleted the laravel folder. The laravel development server has started so I guess it works now.

Comment: Great! Mark your answer as solution then.